# How to get context rendering in web forms

Tags: presentation

Does anyone know how to get a context rendering in Sitecore Web Forms?

There is a `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering` in the Sitecore MVC, but I can't seem to find the same for Web Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow, it's been a while. It isn't completely clear to me exactly what you are after, but I believe this might be helpful to you.

```
var renderingReference = Sitecore.Context.Page.GetRenderingReference(this);
```

Where 'this' would be your current page control. It *might* be that you need to do `this.Parent` (to get the actual Sublayout responsible for rendering your control) - I unfortunately don't have a Webforms based solution nearby to test.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. 
The need has been gone already, but I will keep the question, in case somebody is to deal with the same thing